# Get COUNT grouped by ENUM field and fill not used enum with 0

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a table

```
class UserModel(BaseModel):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = Column(
        Enum(
            "registered",
            "confirmed",
            "pending",
            name="user_statuses",
        )
    )
```

I wanna query the table and get the COUNT of users grouped by their status and if there is no user with specific status I still wanna return it but with `0`.

For instance let's say I have following users in the database:

```
id    status
1     confirmed
2     confirmed
3     registered
```

As a result I wanna get something like:

```
status     user_count
registered 1
confirmed  2
pending    0
```

how can I achieve such thing?

Comment: Do you have a table `status` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use subqueries with `count()` inside.
If you have a `status` table([result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kTzM47e6YTq7pX4Xih22ds/0)):

```
select s.status, coalesce(u.user_count,0) as user_count
from status s left join 
(select status,count(*) as user_count from users group by status) u on u.status = s.status
```

If you don't have a `status` table ([result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kTzM47e6YTq7pX4Xih22ds/1)):

```
select s.status, coalesce(u.user_count,0) as user_count
from (select unnest(array['registered','confirmed','pending']) as status) s left join 
(select status,count(*) as user_count from users group by status) u on u.status = s.status
```